# Is there any way to set value interval of Amcharts4 animate gauge?

Tags: typescript, angular5, amcharts, amcharts4

I am implementing `amcharts4 animated gauge` in angular and implemeting this example of amcharts

[example](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/animated-gauge/)

I have these configs of  `animated gauge` in my ts file

```
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.GaugeChart);
chart.innerRadius = am4core.percent(82);

/**
 * Normal axis
 */

var axis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
axis.min = 0;
axis.max = 100;
axis.strictMinMax = true;
axis.renderer.radius = am4core.percent(80);
axis.renderer.inside = true;
axis.renderer.line.strokeOpacity = 1;
axis.renderer.ticks.template.strokeOpacity = 1;
axis.renderer.ticks.template.length = 10;
axis.renderer.grid.template.disabled = true;
axis.renderer.labels.template.radius = 40;
axis.renderer.labels.template.adapter.add("text", function (text) {
  return text;
})

/**
 * Axis for ranges
 */

var colorSet = new am4core.ColorSet();

var axis2 = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
axis2.min = 0;
axis2.max = 100;
axis2.renderer.innerRadius = 10
axis2.strictMinMax = true;
axis2.renderer.labels.template.disabled = true;
axis2.renderer.ticks.template.disabled = true;
axis2.renderer.grid.template.disabled = true;

var range0 = axis2.axisRanges.create();
range0.value = 0;
range0.endValue = 50;
range0.axisFill.fillOpacity = 1;
range0.axisFill.fill = colorSet.getIndex(0);

var range1 = axis2.axisRanges.create();
range1.value = 50;
range1.endValue = 100;
range1.axisFill.fillOpacity = 1;
range1.axisFill.fill = colorSet.getIndex(2);

/**
 * Label
 */

this.gaugaeLabel = chart.radarContainer.createChild(am4core.Label);
this.gaugaeLabel.isMeasured = false;
this.gaugaeLabel.fontSize = 12;
this.gaugaeLabel.x = am4core.percent(50);
this.gaugaeLabel.y = am4core.percent(100);
this.gaugaeLabel.horizontalCenter = "middle";
this.gaugaeLabel.verticalCenter = "bottom";
this.gaugaeLabel.text = "0";


/**
 * Hand
 */

this.gaugaeHand = chart.hands.push(new am4charts.ClockHand());
this.gaugaeHand.axis = axis2;
this.gaugaeHand.innerRadius = am4core.percent(20);
this.gaugaeHand.startWidth = 10;
this.gaugaeHand.pin.disabled = true;
this.gaugaeHand.value = 0;

this.gaugaeHand.events.on("propertychanged", function (ev) {
  range0.endValue = ev.target.value;
  range1.value = ev.target.value;
  axis2.invalidate();
});
```

In this example the scale of gauge starts with 0 and end at 100. And the value interval between scale values is 10 like scale values start from zero and displaying like 10 20 30 40 50 60 ... 100. But i want start value 100 and end value 500 and value interval 100 so that i can show the gauge scale values like 100 200 300 400 500. How can i set value interval in amcharts4 animated gauge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set the start and end value of an axis you can use [`axis.min`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/valueaxis/#min_property) and [`axis.max`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/valueaxis/#max_property):

```
axis.min = 100;
axis.max = 500;
```

To show only the values you want on the axis you can use [`axis.renderer.minGridDistance`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/valueaxis/#max_property).

[Here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LarERp) I created a code pen to show the behavior.